# Having difficulty running pygame 2.7

Tags: windows, pygame

Every time I try to run Pygame 2.7 version I get this prompt:

> Windows cant open this file:
>   File name: pygame-1.9.2b1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd 64.whl
>   To open this file Windows needs to know what program you want to use to open it.
>   Windows can go online to look it up automatically, or you can manually select from a list of programs that are installed on your computer.
>   What do you want to do?
>
> - Use the Web service to find the correct program
> - Select a program from a list of installed programs

How can this be solved?
I've tried many Youtube videos.

Comment: Are you trying to open a file, a program? Other?

Comment: Yes, when I click on run, that's when the issues start. Once I manually chose Notepad++ as a program to open it and I was prompted with this immense coding...I'm so lost.

Comment: Have you tried choosing a program? What are the options?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know which to try.

Comment: Post what options you have.

Comment: My options are: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, Notepad, Paint, Windows Media Player, Word 2016, Internet Explorer, Office XML Handler, Windows Media Center, Windows Photo Viewer, and Word Pad.

Comment: I don't see anything

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader, NotePad, Paint, Windows Media Player, Word 2016, Internet Explorer, Office XML Handler, Windows Media Center, Windows Photo Viewer, and Word Pad

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to open a program and not a file?

Comment: Were you able to see it this time?

Comment: Yes. And it looks like Windows sees it as a file, not a program.

Comment: apologies it's a file

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to open Pygame file that I chose from the Pygame library write codes for game designing. When I try to download file and the problems arises.

Comment: What's the files extension? pygame.py ? pygame.exe ? pygame....?

Comment: `pygame-1.9.2b1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd 64.whl` is python package which you have to install with command `pip install pygame-1.9.2b1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd 64.whl`

Comment: BTW: it is not PyGame 2.7 but PyGame 1.9.2b1 for Python 2.7 64-bit

Comment: Its supposed to be pygame.py

Answer (score 0):

That `.whl` file that you mention needs to be **installed** with a command-line tool called `pip` that comes with python. Assuming you are starting from scratch, here is what you need to do to install python and pygame. Also, as a minor sidenote, you are actually installing **pygame 1.9.2 on python 2.7**. Assuming you are interested in that particular version of python and pygame, here are the steps you need to follow.

1. To install **python 2.7**, you need to first go to the Python Software Foundation's website [here](https://www.python.org/). Go to the download section by clicking on the [latest link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2712/) for python 2.7.12. Scroll down and download either the x86 or x86-64 MSI installer (depending if you are on a 32bit or 64bit platform respectively).
2. Run the MSI installer. Most of the default options should be fine, nothing too tricky here.
3. After you run the installer, you need to add python to the PATH environment variable so that windows actually knows where python is on your computer. To do this, you need to find the **Advanced System Settings** section in your control panel (how to exactly get there varies depending on what Windows version you are on).
4. Once you are there, click the **Environmental Variables...** button. Under **System Variables**, we need to edit the value of the **Path** variable to include `C:\Python27\` at the end of it. If all of the path variable stuff is on one line, you need to add a semicolon to separate it from the other paths in the list.
5. Congrats, now **python 2.7** should be installed at this point! To test it out, open up the command prompt and type `python`. It should open up the interpreter in the command line and should be working.
6. Assuming it is working, exit out of the python interpreter. In the command prompt, type `python -m pip install pygame`. This should automatically install pygame for you. If you really want to use your wheel file, `cd` to the directory where it is installed and type `python -m pip install pygame-1.9.2b1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd 64.whl`.

Once that is done, you should have both python and pygame installed! Test it out in your IDE of choice (I personally use [Geany](https://www.geany.org/Download/Releases)) and start writing some code! Let me know if these instructions are clear enough.

Comment: Thank you I will give it a shot!

Comment: @user7082375 If it works, just hit the accept button when you get a chance. If not, add a comment here letting me know what is not working or what error you are getting and I will try to clarify some details.

Comment: What step is exactly not work? Is it with the python installation process or the pygame installation process? If python still appears to not be installed, it sometimes takes a while for the Environmental PATH variable to change, so you might need to close and reopen your command prompt or restart your computer.

Comment: I meticulously did everything over. I installed Python 3.4.2 and tested it confirming it worked. Then I went to the Pygame library and chose the binary file(for Window's 64 bit) that's compatible with the  Python version I chose. As the same before, when I try to open that Pygame file, it prompts me to choose the program that I would like to open that file with. May I add this Pygame version is already pipped. Just not making any sense...

Comment: If you already used pip to install pygame and saw a message like `Successfully installed pygame...` in your command prompt after you ran that command, then that is it for installation! You don't need to use the .whl file. To test if pygame is truly installed and working, just type `python` in the command prompt to open the python shell. When you see a prompt like >>>, try typing `import pygame` and hit enter. If just another >>> appears, then it is installed, otherwise there will be an error.

Comment: To create a game with pygame, you need to write some code in a text file (using say, notepad) and save it with a .py extension. Then you run that code in your IDE or using the command prompt, typing `python whatever_the_path_to_your_file/my_game_files_name.py`. [Here](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/pygame/basics/part1/) is some sample code you can try. Copy and paste the "simplest barebones app" code into a .py text file and try running that instead.

Comment: I got a prompt in the python shell that says 'python' isn't defined smh

Comment: In that case, the Environment path variable hasn't been setup. If my instructions for steps 3 and 4 didn't work, you can run python in a more tedious way by running the python exe. For python 2.7, instead of typing `python` you can type `C:\\Python27\python.exe`. For python 3.5,  you would need to find the path for the python 3.5 exe and use that instead. Out of curiosity, what version of windows are you on?

Comment: Windows 7. Whats weird is that on my previous laptop I install everything with no issues. I was actually an older laptop with an older processor and windows 7, which I am so shocked that im having issues now trying to launch Pygame.

Comment: That is weird! Looking at the first image in [this](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) link, if you installed python 3+, there is a checkbox `Add Python 3.5 to PATH` that you can check during the installation process that automatically adds python to the path and saves all of this configuration trouble. If you checked that, everything should be fine. Otherwise, you can run python using the python.exe inside  `C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35` since you installed python 3 instead. Not sure what is causing the issue at this point.

Comment: I'll go back again and trace my tracks